# Issues in sonar analysis through Maven of php project

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to do sonar analysis through maven of a php project.

I have gone followed all the instruction mentioned on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin, have done all the necessary set up and changes mentioned.

I am getting following error messages after execution of the command mvn sonar:sonar from project directory.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (d
        efault-cli) on project espritKM: Can not execute Sonar: PHPMD execution failed w
        ith returned code '255'. Please check the documentation of PHPMD to know more ab
        out this failure. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you should run the analysis in Debug mode (i.e. with "-X") in order to find which exact PHPMD command is launched and then run it manually in a shell to see what's happening.